# awk: fatal: 1 is invalid as number of arguments for match

Tags: awk

`myfile` looks like

```
Split level: train 67.0%
importance 0.17
Score metric (accuracy_score): 0.986
Score metric (precision_score): 0.903
```

I want to extract the accuracy score (here it is `0.986`) by awk:

```
$ awk '/Score metric \(accuracy_score\):/ { match(/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ *$/); substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) }' myfile
awk: fatal: 1 is invalid as number of arguments for match
```

What does the error mean here? I don't have `1` in my awk program.

How can I correct my program to make it work?

What is your better solution?

Comment: you want to get the solution to your problem or you want to understand the error message?

Comment: You've only passed one argument to `match`; that's what the error message is telling you.

Comment: Isn't $0 the default second argument for `match`? @Tom

Comment: Nope...`match` takes 2 (or more) arguments, `match(string, regexp)`. If you want to match against `$0`, you need to do so explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have stated the issue with the number of match parameters... this can be found in the **awk** manual.  The following answer is quick and easy -- avoiding the match() and substr() functions.  It outputs the last field when your pattern is found.  LC_ALL=C is used because your match criterion and number are all representable in ASCII -- the script will run faster in this mode.

```
LC_ALL=C awk '/Score metric \(accuracy_score\):/ { print $NF }'
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell if `LC_ALL=C` is an environment variable used by awk or gawk (so that I can find a reference for it)? What does it do?

Comment: Here is another article that may be helpful that talks a little more about locale variables and also provides some nice tips about idiomatic **awk**: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/ten-awk-tips-tricks-and-pitfalls/

Answer (score 2):

If you stick to awk, I would do:

```
awk -F':\\s*' '/Score metric \(accuracy_score\)/{print $2}' file
```

In your codes, you used `match()` function, in man page:

```
match(s, r [, a])  s is the string, r is the regex, and optional a is array.
```

You gave only a `/..../` to `match()` this would be interpreted by awk as a boolean, it does `$0~/.../`, so the result it true. and boolean.true in awk has int value `1`.

Here you found the `1`(one).

*awk what I meant above is gnu awk.

Comment: Thanks. In my original program,  I add $0 as first arg to `match`, but there is no match. Why is it? The program after adding $0 is `awk '/Score metric \(accuracy_score\):/ { match(/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ *$/); substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) }' myfile`.

Comment: `I add $0 as first arg to match` @Tim I don't see that you did this.

Comment: Because you do not print the substr()?

Comment: @Tim what I am seeing is, you did `match(/whatever/)` read my answer, it explained this.

Comment: I meant I add $0 to my original program.

Comment: @emil: right. but isn't the default action on a string is to print it? So I think it will print the returned string from `substr`.

Comment: @Tim sorry I don't understand, I don't see the `$0` in your `match()`, where did you add it?

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to added it in my first comment. Should be `awk '/Score metric \(accuracy_score\):/ { match($0, /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ *$/); substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) }' myfile`

Comment: @Tim: nothing is default in awk. you have expressions { statements } or expressions or { statements }, if you only have a expression and it is != 0, awk will print, if you use print as a statement, awk will print. I.e.: awk 1, awk '1{print}' and awk '{print}' will all print

Comment: Can you explain if your program is better than mine after adding `$0` and `print`, which is now `awk '/Score metric \(accuracy_score\):/ { match($0, /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ *$/); print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) }' myfile`

Comment: @Tim I think (not 100% sure), mine would be a little faster than yours. since you process the line 3 times, `/Score.../  ;   match(...); and substr(...)` mine max. twice.

Comment: Kim's program is smaller and neater. Lesser risk for bugs and easier for other people (than yourself) to understand

Comment: @emil there definitely ARE defaults in awk (the default condition is true and default action given a true condition in the condition section is print $0) but printing a string by calling substr() in the middle of an action block isn't one of them!

Comment: @Ed: Are there other cases `print` can be omitted and still expected?

Comment: @Tim - No there aren't.

Answer (score 0):

if u just wanna capture the score, it's easier to let `FS / OFS` to do it for you and skip ***all*** function calls

```
echo '
Split level: train 67.0%
importance 0.17
Score metric (accuracy_score): 0.986
Score metric (precision_score): 0.903' |
```

---

```
mawk 'NF *= 1 < NF' FS='^Score metric [(]accuracy_score[)][:] *' OFS=
```

---

```
0.986
```