# fatal: 4 is invalid as number of arguments for split

Tags: bash, awk

I wrote the following simple awk script to split a string based on the delimiter "\n", and store the resulting substrings in an array, and subsequently print the array:

```
#!/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN{

  string = "word1\nword2\nword3\nword4"
  split(string, a, "\n", seps)
}

END{
   for (var in a)
     print var
}
```

Initially, I had the first line in my script as shown below:

```
#!/bin/gawk
```

Then I ran into the error highlighted in the following post:

[syntax error in awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/648453/syntax-error-in-awk)

I had followed the example provided in the gawk user manual in using the `split()` method in my script:

[9.1.4 String-Manipulation Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)

I also found another post related to setting the environment variable `LC_ALL=C`:

[awk: fatal: 1 is invalid as number of arguments for match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34682706/awk-fatal-1-is-invalid-as-number-of-arguments-for-match)

So in the bash environment from which I ran the script, I set the environment variable as

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

In spite of all this, the error persists.

Would appreciate your thoughts.

TIA

Comment: What version of `gawk` are you using? The `seps` argument was added in 4.0.

Comment: `LC_ALL=C` has nothing to do with how many arguments `split()` has. The syntax error in the question you referenced also has nothing to do with how many arguments `split()` has. Please [edit] your question to show us the actual error message you're asking for help to debug.

Comment: @EdMorton I have highlighted the error in the title of the post. Rest the script is exactly the way I am trying to run it.

Comment: The version of gawk I have is GNU AWK 3.1.7. May be that explains the error...Can someone point me to the documentation that highlights the signature of split() prior to gawk version 4?

Comment: It may be present but it's not highlighted in the subject, the subject is not a complete error message, the error message should be in the body of the text formatted as a Code Block, and adding a link to some other error message that you aren't asking about while not including the one you are asking about is misleading at best.

Comment: Your version of gawk is 13 years out of date, you should get a new one as you're missing some bug fixes and a lot of very useful extensions/features. In that version `split()` was just like any other awk variant with 3 args - a string, an array, and an optional field separator.

Comment: The variables `a` and `seps` are undefined in your program (i.e. empty).

Comment: @user1934428 those variables would be populated by the call to `split()`, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html

Comment: @EdMorton: Good to know. Still, my awk man-page (MacOS awk) shows only 3 parameters for `split`.  It does not provide the 4th parameter, `seps`.

Comment: @user1934428 the 4th arg is a gawk extension introduced in gawk 4.0 as [mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76657954/fatal-4-is-invalid-as-number-of-arguments-for-split?noredirect=1#comment135153098_76657954) and described in the article I linked.